# What is a reasonable approach to deal with other Arqade users that seem to be ratting on you?

Tags: discussion, abuse

What should I do if I believe users are just saying things to make me look bad? This happened with NoneOfYourBuisness and now it's happening with me. I don't want to delete my account because I want to help people. What should I do?

I'm done.

Comment: Have you considered that, perhaps, things are being said about the quality of the content you post, and that that quality could be significantly improved?

Comment: You could start by listening to other people when they recommend that you *up your quality*.

Comment: We're not trying to make you look bad, we are responding negatively to posts we think are bad though.

Comment: Also, can you provide some examples of where you think we are saying things that make you look bad, so that we're all on the same page.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I like your avatar.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Yeah, I've been wanting to ask where he found that!

Comment: Also, we're not just trying to be mean or insult you personally. We just think you should try to improve the quality of your posts so that you can help people better.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Well, maybe OrigamiRobot is trying to be mean. You can never tell with robots.

Comment: I think you are getting very nice and constructive advice in this question, I hope you listen to it. Ignore the downvotes and read the comments and answer(s)

Comment: @jmfsg Down-votes make the question/answer a bad one. Even though the downvoting on this site is 100% opinion based and not whether or not it's constructive.

Comment: Voting works a little different on Meta.  Also people are frustrated.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I think you're confusing cause and effect...

Comment: @YoungGuilo Downvotes on a **meta** question mean very little.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Then why have it?

Comment: Hi, I'm Grace Note, a Community Manager here at Stack Exchange. I'll be taking some extensive look into this situation and would also like to speak with you directly at some point. I'm in the middle of a meeting at the moment so I cannot do it this moment but this should be over in about an hour and I'll be here.

Comment: @YoungGuilo It's a holdover from how SO and SE developed. I'd be happy to go into more detail about it, but that's not very relevant to this post, so I'll not derail it any further.

Comment: Alright, my meeting is over. Would it be possible for me to pull you into chat to have some talk about the situation here, how to parse it, and how we can get out of the bad parts amicably?

Comment: @GraceNote yes that would be great.

Comment: Alright. I've created a room for you. You should have a message in your inbox from me from there, please join me in there when you're ready.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm Grace Note, a Stack Exchange Community Manager. I'd like to address the portions of this question that have yet to be addressed by the community... which is to say the whole of it. Let's dispense with specifics of an individual and march onwards to the inquiry given!

I want to start off that at its core, our model behaves like an adaptation of the golden rule of debates - **Never target a person, always target the argument**. In our case, we'd sub "argument" for "contribution", being questions and answers. Users themselves only have reputation, which can only exist in a positive value. Votes can only be applied to contributions, and the reasoning behind votes should likewise follow suit. The first response to receiving downvotes should be to check if there is work to be done to reverse them. Most users on the network operate within our guidelines.

For the above reasons, thus, **personal defamation isn't all that tolerable**. In some cases, if not meant to be explicitly malicious, users may go overboard in their treatment without realizing the harm they're causing. If, be it in comments or chats, you feel that users reach a point where they are attacking not your content, but you as a person, then this is not appropriate. What are reasonable approaches to this?

- **Flag obvious toxicity**. If comments are unquestionably rude against your person, you can flag them as such.
- **Collect evidence**. This is an extremely important portion of handling treatment by other users outside of the direct context that it happens (like if there are comments across multiple posts in multiple weeks). Samples and links to specific incidents of maltreatment are much more valuable than verbal testimonials. By providing these samples, it illustrates the reality of the situation, though take care to listen to if the reality had been intended otherwise.
- **Talk it out**. Make it known that it feels like people are insulting or humiliating you. Explain how you feel and try to reason with the community. I've been with this community from the start - we may be ornery folk when it comes to maintaining our quality, but we are all reasonable people and are open to discussion and explaining our position. It stands for this reason that we as a community should offer the same respect back when approached in this manner, and talk things through calmly. No matter how frustrating a situation is for either side, anger never really makes a problem go away, it only has no impact or aggravates the situation for worse.
- **Ask for moderator mediation**. If you find yourself at an impasse with the community, or if you have some hesitance about the interpretation of events, the moderator team on Arqade is able to intervene as an impartial observer to overlook the turn of events and try to soften things out. The Community Team from Stack Exchange (which includes myself) is also available to mediate the situation.

Our focus as a network is on content, not people. But this applies to how the mechanics of the site work, and while we're in the realm of the mechanics, we all do our best to follow this. But when we're outside the realm of the mechanics, we're still a community, and one of people. We all have the capability of offering each other due respect, so let us exercise this in our engagements, on both sides of any of these kinds of encounters.

Answer (score 22):

I'll be blunt: I've noticed a pattern with your contributions, and I don't like what I see.  You tend to post several questions and answers within a very small period of time.  This means your overall *quantity* is high, but your average *quality* is incredibly low.  If the serial downvoting script is getting triggered because a single user is posting such quantity of low quality contributions in a short period of time, I'm of the opinion that we, as a community, need to do something.  My view is that the problem is your contributions.

You also like to answer bounty questions with answers that don't source anything, and very often turn out to be wrong.  That tells me you're not here to help, but to gain rep.  This is not the focus you should have, as rep will happen organically with high quality contributions.  It will come even faster, actually, than just flooding the site with lots of low quality questions and answers.

---

I've taken the liberty of going through a few of your contributions to give some critique on them:

[What are the rules of spawning zombie pigmen from nether portals?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/126937/20456) +1/-5

I honestly have no idea if this answer is correct or not; I haven't voted on it at all.  I've tried to point you in the right direction, but you seem to focus more on appeasing the commenters than providing correct information.

You then deleted it and re-posted it, which is exactly the wrong thing to do.  Your duplicate answer I *did* downvote, because you didn't re-post it to make it better.  You reposted it to get rid of the downvotes already on it.  That's a straightforward abuse of the system, and a classic example of bounty hunting.

[How do I pick up an Ectoplasmer in Runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126980/how-do-i-pick-up-an-ectoplasmator-in-runescape) +0/-0

This one's kinda borderline.  You've shown what you've tried, so that's good.  What's bad is that you've repeated the title in the body, and without that, your question is a one-liner.  We like a little more context and effort shown than just that.  It doesn't need to be much, but if your entire question can fit into a single line, that's usually a good indicator that you need to flesh it out a little more.

[What are the actual names of the stages in Centipede?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126323/what-are-the-actual-names-of-the-stages-in-centipede) +3/-5

This one I did downvote, because I see no usefulness at all to it.  Add in the lack of effort prior to asking, and we have the reason why this is at a negative score.  Doing a little bit of research before asking would've prevented this.

[Why is my level decreasing during inactivity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125464/why-is-my-level-decreasing-during-inactivity) +1/0

This one's alright.  It displays a misunderstanding of how the system works, which gets resolved in the answer.  We specialize in ensuring people get their facts straight when they misunderstand them.  You could flesh this out a bit more, but adding more details would've probably indicated that what you think is happening, wasn't.

[Is it possible to fire a lock-on Rocket Launcher in “Dumbfire” mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126666/is-it-possible-to-fire-a-lock-on-rocket-launcher-in-dumbfire-mode/126670#126670) +4/-12

This one is out and out wrong.  You did barely any research before answering, and didn't provide a source for your information at all.  Most likely because I believe you didn't actually *do* any.  If anything, this answer should be deleted.

[How can I easily select an enemy colony with a large space station in orbit?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/121543/8350) (10K only)

You answered this question with zero research.  You don't play the game at all, as the answer makes rather obvious.  This, too, was a case of bounty hunting.

---

For the most part, you ARE gaining rep, in spite of your contributions.  If you want to be a valued member of the community, try to follow these steps:

1. Put more effort into your questions.  They should be more than one line.  They should tell us what you tried.  They should not be easily Googled.
2. Put a lot more effort into your answers.  When possible, include a link to where you pulled it from.  If you tested it in game, tell us how you tested it.
3. Don't answer questions of games you don't play.  If you do, try to put more than five minutes of research into doing so.
4. Focus on helping people with high quality contributions.  A few paragraphs would not be amiss.  Add in some sources if you can.

All of this boils down to investing effort into your contributions.  We WANT users that spend time making the best answers they can.  We DON'T want users that answer stuff solely to gain rep.

Comment: Note: This is a well researched, well presented and thoughtful answer. Clearly quite some effort went into it. It is getting lots of upvotes.

Comment: @fredley Your comment is very explanatory and clear.  That's why I upvoted it.

Comment: I am a power hungry mod, so I'll delete your comments *and I love mod abuse so here I am, in ur comment furthering ur joke -badp*

Comment: Just to be clear: I would not have asked questions if I know where to find the answers. I couldn't care about bounties or reputation. I'm for helping the people. I have a youtube channel with guides and such. I know how to help. When I do it gets downvoted because of "No research". I know the answer. I don't need to research. The question on Dumbfire mode is technically correct since the weapon he was using didn't have that capability. OrigamiRobot is babying the fredley's comment which makes this entire thing seem like a joke. I don't appreciate jokes. -10 on a serious question. Seems legit.

Comment: @YoungGuilo When **ten people** think your question is bad, there might just be something to it, you know?

Comment: @YoungGuilo Votes on meta don't mean the same thing as votes on the main site. They're often used to express disagreement or agreement. These users disagree that users are trying to make you look bad, and vote accordingly. There's no Rep gain/loss here.

Comment: @YoungGuilo The problem is, *nowhere in your questions do you ever allude to that*.  All we get are one-liners that can be boiled down to, "I have this problem.  How do I fix it?".  Adding in context is a **good** thing.  And if you know the answer, *where did you get it from?*  Did you research it in-game?  How?  Find it online?  Add the link.  Technically correct is bad when you allude to all weapons of that type working like that.  Restrict it to that specific weapon.  Add some effort, dude!  That's all we're asking!

Comment: @YoungGuilo [You don't know how to google?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126685/errors-with-starting-runescape)

Comment: @Sconibulus Look at my main account. It shows downvoting on questions that a genuine and that I really need help on.

Comment: And as a sidenote, "I don't need to research" is something the community doesn't agree with.  Prove your claims.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I don't know if anyone else has pointed it out at all, but votes on Meta generally mean I agree/I disagree with whatever is being proposed, and they don't actually affect your site rep. Just so you know. :)

Comment: @YoungGuilo Whether your questions are *genuine* has no bearing on those downvotes, I assume. It's more that your questions are *oneliners with hardly any information*. How do you expect anyone to answer that?

Comment: @fbueckert I did on the question about Zombie pigmen in the portals. I gave wiki evidence. That isn't enough!?!?!?!?

Comment: @YoungGuilo As far as I can tell, no one but you can find that wiki evidence.

Comment: It was in the Trivia section. I even put it in the answer! Everyone downvoted it because it was "un-useful"!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @YoungGuilo Yelling in the comments like this is incredibly unhelpful to everyone involved. I understand you are obviously feeling distress over this stuff, but I think maybe stepping away for a bit to collect your thoughts and calm down some might be best.

Comment: I recommend that all of you move this conversation into a chatroom, instead of having an all out comment war in this meta post.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Thanks for you calming technique but even when I have good points such as that everything still boils down to "your doing something wrong".

Comment: @YoungGuilo I suggest you go back to your questions, re-examine them, and reconsider what you did wrong.  Take our advice, not just mines.  Remember, meta is a community effort; we're trying to help you improve your Q&A, not admonish you for it. Take everyone's advice as friendly advice, and try to repair what you've done. Thanks!

Comment: @YoungGuilo The point is that you *are* doing something wrong. Not with *every* post, but with a *whole damn lot* of posts. And we've been trying to tell you, trying to show you, fixed your posts for you and finally resorted to letting the system tell you with downvotes.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I've been keeping quiet all this time, but this: "I couldn't care about bounties or reputation" is an outright lie. Yes you do care about reputation as evidenced by the various meta questions on how to maximize your reputation and you care about it more than many of the regulars on this site. We are not stupid, so don't assume that we are.

Comment: That said, it's *fine* to care about reputation. Encouraged even. But perspective is important. One upvote can erase **five** downvotes.

Comment: I care about my reputation, but not so much the points, if that makes sense. I don't believe it matters if you've got 15 rep or 150k, people can make mistakes. Decisions can be the wrong one. At the same time I've met people with 100 rep who post clear, concise Q&As, and people with 5000 who don't seem to care either way (usually they got lucky and got a highly visible question or two, or avoid answering anything but the top tags)

Answer (score 7):

For the record, I like you. You seem to be a pretty decent member of this community, you actively try and find out what it is that you're doing wrong so you can fix it (such as this question here), and you seem to love [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), which in my books is a big plus :).

However, as other people are saying, your questions & answers could use some improvement. I'm going to lay out how I write questions and answers as an example - there are other ways to phrase your Q&As, but generally this is what works for me:

### Questions

- **Title:** It generally should be phrased as a question. Also, people shoud be able to read your title and instantly know what the problem is. Compare

  - *Problem with Redstone*, to
  - *How can I get three Pistons to activate using the same Redstone line?*
- **Body:** The body should be composed of three main sections: Context, Research and Question. This is kind of like writing a short essay, with an Introduction, Body (which shows research) and Conclusion:

  - *Context*: Where does this problem occur?
  - *Research*: What have you done to try and solve the problem, or what have you found whilst researching? If it's a technical problem, list some specifications (Java version number, amount of RAM, CPU speed etc)
  - *Question*: Pretty much should sum up what you've just described. *"Even with all this info at my disposal, my Pistons still won't activate. Is there something I'm missing?"*

Example (bold are links):

> #### How do I do the thing?
>
> In *Awesome Game Title 2: Extreme Edition*, there is a section of the level where X happens. You can get here by opening 3 doors, talking to Mr Z, and performing a somersault into this wall.
>
> **Here** is some stuff **online**, that relates to the question about **the thing**.
>   I've also tried blorking the thing, sporking the thing, and even torqing the thing, but to no avail.
>
> Even knowing XYZ about the thing, it still doesn't Blork correctly. Is there something I'm missing?

As a real-world example: [Is it possible to stop the Madman from escaping his yacht?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121478/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-madman-from-escaping-his-yacht)

### Answers

Generally, I try to remember that we are trying to *solve a problem* the user is facing. Even if the answer is "No, it's not possible", I at least try and find a workaround solution that may help them. In some cases, it even may be exactly what they're after anyway, and they just couldn't phrase it that way in the question themselves!

Again, this can be a lot like writing an essay (Introduction, Body, Conclusion), however, if the answer boils down to Yes/No, I generally put that in the first sentence. After all, that's what they're after. In any case, just make sure to back up your answer with links, and quotes (and links to the quotes). Images and videos are nice, but should only *add* to your answer, not be the sole source of it.

Examples (bold are links again):

#### Q: How do I do the thing?

#### A:

> You've got to have the *Sword of Neverending Awesome* before attempting to Blork the Thing. Otherwise, Mr Z won't open the fourth door, which is key to all of this.
>
> To get the Sword of Neverending Awesome, head to QwertyTown, and order a mead from the local innkeeper. Perform 5 somersaults, one on each table in the Pub. You'll get the achievement *"Move your body"* (If you haven't already), and one of the QwertyTownians will present you with the sword.
>
> Here is a short video, detailing the process: (Video embed)

Or:

#### Q: Is it possible to jump the mountain?

(This question technically calls for a Yes/No answer)

#### A:

> **Yes**, it is possible. You'll need the *Boots of Extreme Comfiness*, and need to have levelled your charater's Springiness attribute to 11.

(Most people would stop here, however, as I mentioned earlier, we're here to *solve a problem* the user is facing. I would then continue:

> You can get the boots from the Shopkeeper in QwertyTown on Tuesdays and Thursdays. Here's the **wiki link** for the boots.
>
> As for levelling your character's springiness, I've found it easiest to complete the training grounds in the **Krazy Kaverns** first (an instant +5 to both Springiness **and** Awesomeness). The rest you can gain through side quests. See the **attributes wiki**, which lists ways to increase stats quickly

Some examples:

- [How to password protect my ps3 console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82639/how-to-password-protect-my-ps3-console/82642#82642)
- [Why do my neighbour deals keep ending prematurely?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110458/why-do-my-neighbour-deals-keep-ending-prematurely/110530#110530)
- [Animals won't spawn, even though on an older map they will](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/animals-wont-spawn-even-though-on-an-older-map-they-will/114310#114310)
- [What is the fastest way to get money in GTA San Andreas?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70404/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-money-in-gta-san-andreas/96663#96663)

Every answer is different of course. This is just a general guide.

One last point: Humor can go a long way (but shouldn't be the entire focus of the question/answer). See:

- Q: [How much of my money does my Mum spend when she buys me things?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126859/how-much-of-my-money-does-my-mum-spend-when-she-buys-me-things)
- A: [Any way to make your crew stop attacking a system?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/101782/any-way-to-make-your-crew-stop-attacking-a-system/101786#101786)

Comment: Thanks, +1 for torqing. Oh I liked the help too :)